# How to find a free TPM handle for saving a new key pair object?

Tags: go, cryptography, handle, tpm, key-pair

I am new to TPM and currently working on a project that involves generating and storing serveral key pairs using tpm. I would like to know how to find an available TPM handle that can be used to save a new key pair object. I have searched for information on this topic but haven't found a clear answer.Here are some specific questions I have:

1. How can I programmatically determine if a TPM handle points to an empty area and is free to be used for saving a new key pair object?
2. Are there any specific functions or methods in the Go-TPM package that can help me with this task?
3. Are there any considerations or best practices I should be aware of when selecting a TPM handle for storing key pairs?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant documentation that can help me understand how to find an available TPM handle for saving a new key pair object in tpm.Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Manually creating key pairs using specific handles like 0x81010001 or 0x81010002.
2. Attempting to save the key pairs in TPM persistent memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Go TPM library, but from a low level point of view you can use the [TPM2_GetCapability](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part3_Commands_pub.pdf) command using [TPM_CAP_HANDLES](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part2_Structures_pub.pdf) (0x00000001) as capability parameter, 0x81000000 as property parameter and for example 32 as propertyCount parameter.

This will return a list of allocated handles in the handle range for persistent objects, choose an index that is not in the list and is in the range 0x81000000 - 0x817FFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

There is a registry at

https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/Registry-of-Reserved-TPM-2.0-Handles-and-Localities-Version-1.2-Revision-1.00_pub.pdf

which lists available ranges.

Other guidance: The TPM may have only ~7 key slots, and some are already used. It is a scarce resource!

Generally, save keys off the TPM. They are encrypted and therefore safe. Saving keys in TPM NV should be reserved for the rare use cases where no external persistent storage is available. This is typically in the pre-OS environment, before disk is available.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance . I have a quick follow-up question: Are TPM-generated public/private key blobs encrypted and safe to store directly on disk? If not, what's the best practice for encrypting them before saving them in disk storage in case of not using tpm storage? @ken

Appreciate your insights!